# Pasar valor de variable de jQuery a un input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tengo esta función en jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready", function () {
        $("#area_tabla table tr td").click(function () {
            var celda = $(this);
            alert(celda.html());
            console.log(celda.html())

        });
    });
</script>
```

Lo que hace es que al momento de seleccionar una celda de una tabla me muestra el valor de esa celda en un `alert`. Lo que quiero es que ese valor se le asigne a un `<input>`

```
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes conseguir mediante el método [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) para pasar el valor:

```js
var celda = 'algo';

$('input[type=text]').prop({'value': celda});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Tu código pondría el texto "algo" a todos los `<input>` que se tengan en la vista actual, ¿es correcto? Me parece que la pregunta va más enfocada a que se requiere un texto a un solo `<input>`.

Comment: @Flxtr . - Creo que la pregunta se basa en como pasar el valor a un input...Mi respuesta es la base para que pueda trabajar sobre el...

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu `<input>` se declara así:

```
<input type="text" id="txtCeldaModificar"/>
```

Entonces tu código de jQuery quedará de la siguiente forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready", function () {
        $("#area_tabla table tr td").click(function () {
            var celda = $(this);
            $("#txtCeldaModificar").val(celda.html());
        });
    });
</script>
```